# How to resolve Package subpath './package.json' is not defined by "exports" error

Tags: javascript, typescript, protractor, cucumberjs

```
  Getting below error while running cucumber.js file using protractor 
  E/launcher - Error: Error [ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED] [ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED]: Package subpath './package.json' is not defined by "exports" in E:\Tutorial\CucumberProject\node_modules\@cucumber\cucumber\package.json
at new NodeError (internal/errors.js:322:7)
at throwExportsNotFound (internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:322:9)
at packageExportsResolve (internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:545:3)
at resolveExports (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:450:36)
at Function.Module._findPath (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:490:31)
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:888:27)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:746:27)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:93:18)
at ModuleLoader.require (E:\Tutorial\CucumberProject\node_modules\@serenity-js\core\src\io\ModuleLoader.ts:68:20)
```

[16:12:08] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 100

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and `npm install --save-dev @babel/helper-compilation-targets` worked for me.

Comment: It didn't work for me, still the same error